# Magento 2 : Cron Job Set

Tags: magento2

I want to run my cron job every 2 hour for importing product . so i have use below code for that.

Using this code my first cron is run perfectly but i don't know when it will run second time ? is it run after two hour consider after completion of first one ?

```
        <schedule_generate_every>120</schedule_generate_every>
        <schedule_ahead_for>120</schedule_ahead_for>
        <schedule_lifetime>20</schedule_lifetime>
        <history_cleanup_every>10080</history_cleanup_every>
        <history_success_lifetime>21600</history_success_lifetime>
        <history_failure_lifetime>21600</history_failure_lifetime>
    <use_separate_process>1</use_separate_process>
```

i just need to run this cron while completion of my product ( 1000 number of product ) import every time. and it will take approx 2 hour to complete this import process of importing . 
so what i need to set value in this code ?

any idea please share !

If i set 15 minute then second cron is waiting till complete previous process then start after complete first process ?

```
 <schedule_generate_every>15</schedule_generate_every>
 <schedule_ahead_for>15</schedule_ahead_for>
```

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing default cron configuration, you'd better define your desired frequency in your concrete cron task configuration

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-tut.html#cron-tut-crontab

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="custom_cronjob" instance="Magento\SampleMinimal\Cron\Test" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

> The preceding **crontab.xml** runs the Magento/SampleMinimal/Cron/Test.php class once per minute, resulting in a row being added to the cron_schedule table.

**update**

> Verify your custom cron group

```
php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run --group="custom_crongroup"
```

Comment: i have created new cron group for that . can you please let me know when second process run after completed first one using my code ?

Comment: Check my update, https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/54726/camit1dk